# Android Studio - automatically write item from suggestions popup

Tags: android-studio, code-completion

In Android Studio I changed the tab key function from file > settings > keymap. I chose to remove all other bindings from tab key (mistake!!). And now I can't get auto-complete to work like before.

I want to select an item from the auto-complete pop-up then press tab to complete the word (I think this the default behaviour):

[image]

But when I press tab it "completes the sentence" and puts my cursor at the end of the line:

[image]

I don't want this, I want to just complete the word and the cursor to stay in place. This is my current configuration for tab:

[image]

How do I get the default behaviour back? I really don't want to reinstall Android Studio and it is driving me crazy.

--------------- edit ---------------

"Complete current statement" binding doesn't work:

[image]

Now when I press tab nothing happens, it doesn't auto complete at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem. Had to bind "Choose lookup item replace" to tab key to get the default / correct behaviour.
[image]